# What is difference between WPS and WPS-AUTH?

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-protected-setup

I am using `WifiManager` in Android to get list of wifis, the result is a `List<ScanResult>` and each `ScanResult` has `capabilities` property. This has details about encryption and other stuff as well.

My interest is in WPS, I need to find WPS supporting networks around. But sometimes the flag is `[WPS]` and sometimes `[WPS-AUTH]`. What is the difference?